# android polyline decoder shows StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android app where it will collect the overview_polyline->points string from the google maps api. For testing sake i have directly copied it(overview_polyline->points) and used as shown in the below code. I am using Polyutil to decode it:

```
List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode("yxkpA_sjgMoAXuA@{GHeAFo@Jg@P[FcDHiCFu@B}@DkATiAFi@Hw@FcAKmAA[zG@n@DjAFpAPhB`@vBRt@`@|@dAbCg@F{B?eA?BpAAjC?vAC^W|@Ir@GdBe@hCm@lDpCl@|D~@J@?`AHdEAxGAVGZe@jBOnBzDLnGWPDFNRjDAjAG~@S|CCn@v@BXF?`@LtBEHOESC[BKBIJWWA?@?VV?PDbACJB?d@Ix@MRhBANABXRNDx@BBD@VD@FAj@?NB|@HAZLtBAf@CR");
```

I got the string from the below google direction api result:

```
 "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "yxkpA_sjgMoAXuA@{GHeAFo@Jg@P[FcDHiCFu@B}@DkATiAFi@Hw@FcAKmAA[zG@n@DjAFpAPhB`@vBRt@`@|@dAbCg@F{B?eA?BpAAjC?vAC^W|@Ir@GdBe@hCm@lDpCl@|D~@J@?`AHdEAxGAVGZe@jBOnBzDLnGWPDFNRjDAjAG~@S|CCn@v@BXF?`@LtBEHOESC[BKBIJWWA?@?VV?PDbACJB?d@Ix@MRhBANABXRNDx@BBD@VD@FAj@?NB|@HAZLtBAf@CR"
         },
```

When i run the app it says `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=268; index=268`

Comment: Does the error is in line decode?